# Protobuf-3: How to resolve missing method "getIdCase()" ? Classes generated with '--experimental_allow_proto3_optional '

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I used the proto3_optional, and getting this xxCase() method missing on field that are 'optional'. Is there a workaround for this?

Generated message class "muni.model.Model$Person" missing method "getId**Case**"

NoSuchMethodException: muni.model.Model$Person.getId**Case()**

Note: I need to retain hasXX() method working for validating objects, and JsonFormat.printer(myproto) for deserializing.

Proto object

```proto
message Person{
  //Output only
  optional string id = 3; // "muni.model.Model$Person" missing method "getIdCase"
  optional string firstName = 4; // optional added to test hasFirstName()
  optional string lastName = 5;
  optional string email = 6;
  optional string phone1 = 7;
  optional string phone2 = 8;
  PostalAddress address = 9; //For objects no need for optional, hasAddress() works
  bool dirty = 10;//for boolean getDirty() default behavior works, no need for optional
  //Output only
  google.protobuf.Timestamp createTime = 1;
  //Output only
  google.protobuf.Timestamp updateTime = 2;
}
```

Error about missing method

```
app.api.AppException: Error converting Proto to json

    at muni.util.ProtoUtil.toJson(ProtoUtil.java:14)
    at app.PersonResourceTest.personById(PersonResourceTest.java:19)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.runExtensionMethod(QuarkusTestExtension.java:756)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.interceptTestMethod(QuarkusTestExtension.java:663)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:212)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:137)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Generated message class "muni.model.Model$Person" missing method "getIdCase".
    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3.getMethodOrDie(GeneratedMessageV3.java:1847)
    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3.access$1000(GeneratedMessageV3.java:79)
    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3$FieldAccessorTable$SingularFieldAccessor$ReflectionInvoker.<init>(GeneratedMessageV3.java:2164)
    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3$FieldAccessorTable$SingularFieldAccessor.<init>(GeneratedMessageV3.java:2222)
    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3$FieldAccessorTable$SingularStringFieldAccessor.<init>(GeneratedMessageV3.java:2890)
    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3$FieldAccessorTable.ensureFieldAccessorsInitialized(GeneratedMessageV3.java:1977)
    at muni.model.Model$Person.internalGetFieldAccessorTable(Model.java:410)
    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3.getDescriptorForType(GeneratedMessageV3.java:133)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$PrinterImpl.print(JsonFormat.java:764)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$Printer.appendTo(JsonFormat.java:372)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$Printer.print(JsonFormat.java:382)
    at muni.util.ProtoUtil.toJson(ProtoUtil.java:12)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: muni.model.Model$Person.getIdCase()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2109)
    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3.getMethodOrDie(GeneratedMessageV3.java:1844)
    ... 77 more
```

Error happens wherever deserializing is involved

e.g jsonprint, System.out.println(myproto).

```java
import com.google.protobuf.Message;
import com.google.protobuf.MessageOrBuilder;
import com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat;


public class ProtoUtil {
    public static <T extends Message> String toJson(T obj){
        try{
            return JsonFormat.printer().print(obj);
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new AppException("Error converting Proto to json", e);
        }
    }
...
}
```

Comment: this sounds like something to report via the GitHub repo as a problem with the new feature (which is, to be fair, named as "experimental" for exactly this reason)

Comment: Hope this is the right github proj to report this issue https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/7970

Comment: Pretty sure it is, yes

Answer (score 0):

My exception message was

```
Generated message class "com.schx.cluster.protobuf.common.Node" missing method "getNodeDescCase".
2023-06-27 10:04:21.804 [ERROR] [933300846517567488]  agent apply register node : [!!!com.schx.cluster.protobuf.common.Node@3b740915=>java.lang.RuntimeException:Generated message class "com.schx.cluster.protobuf.common.Node" missing method "getNodeDescCase".!!!] error [com.schx.cluster.server.node.DiscoveryApi#register 43] [http-nio-9998-exec-1]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Generated message class "com.schx.cluster.protobuf.common.Node" missing method "getNodeDescCase".
    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3.getMethodOrDie(GeneratedMessageV3.java:1847) ~[protobuf-java-3.11.4.jar:?]
    at
```

I found out that there are two versions of protobuf-java in my dependency, so delete the lower version and you'll be fine!